# Cloudformation support for schema registry in Amazon EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, event-bus

I am working on building a (cross account) messaging system using Amazon EventBridge. I wanted to see if I can use cloudformation to create a schema registry and add schemas in it. But I was not able to find any documentation on this. 
All I could find is support for the following resources:

```
AWS::Events::EventBus
AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
AWS::Events::Rule
```

AWS Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Events.html

It would be great if anyone could help me with this or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like AWS keeps it under the EventSchemas name: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_EventSchemas.html